# how to redirect through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

How to create redirection rule in .htaccess for:-
earlier we have 400+ paths like.

```
/blog/some-path1
/blog/some-path2
```

but now we have paths like.

```
/some-path1
/some-path2
```

How to create single line redirection rule for above redirection without write multiple redirections.

tried below rule but not working
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below rule, I am assuming you know the paths are defined correctly, clear cache beforehand.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^blog/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks abhishek, I have fixed using this below code <code>RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1</code>

Comment: Please help me on this redirection   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269702/path-string-wise-match-redirection-in-htaccess