# path string wise match redirection in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, redirect

How to redirect the path using string compare.

For example: We have path like (1000+ redirections)

```
www.example.com/kb-123
www.example.com/kb-555
www.example.com/kb-666
```

Now using single rule how to redirect all above path's into below path's?

```
www.example.com/article/kb-123
www.example.com/article/kb-555
www.example.com/article/kb-666
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1 [R=301,L]
```